# map a string in each element of an array and assigning in another array in perl

Tags: perl

I have an array `@abc` in which I have the values '1234.txt','2345.txt','3456.txt','4567.txt'.
I want to get all the numeric values from this array and put them in another array say `@xyz`.
I have the regex to do so but using map function I am not able to get the numeric values in another array.
Below code is the snipet of only the section where I am trying the map function:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @abc = ('1234.txt', '2345.txt', '3456.txt', '4567.txt');
foreach my $abc(@abc) {
    my @xyz = map(m/(\d*).txt/, $abc);
    print "@xyz\n";
}
```

With this code, I am getting below output:

```
1234
2345
3456
4567
```

but this is not an array as when I tried changning **print "@xyz\n";** to **print "$xyz[0]\n"**; I am still getting the same output when the output should only be **1234**. I guess the output is in the form of string not array.

Can anyone please help in getting these values in an array.

Comment: Try `my @xyz = map { /(\d+)\.txt$/ } @abc;` instead of the for loop

Comment: Thanks for the reply Håkon Hægland . Actually I want to do foreach as I need to print each element of the array @abc later in my code that is why I am using foreach loop. Can you please let me know if by using foreach how can I take all the numeric elements in the array xyz.

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://pastebin.com/CzmkUKJT) ?

Comment: @johnIT Both `map` and `for` are loops, so you are looping twice around the values, but still just doing them 1 by 1, which is why the output is the same. And you are assigning the array inside the for-loop, so they will not be saved into the array anyway.

Comment: You create 4 arrays with one element each

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your array `@xyz` will only ever contain one value, since your `for` loop takes one array element at the time. Then you assign the value of a single scalar through a `map` statement, to an array declared inside the for-loop, which means the array will be out of scope when the loop is done and no values are ever saved between loop iterations.

```
my @abc = ('1234.txt', '2345.txt', '3456.txt', '4567.txt');
foreach my $abc(@abc) {        # using one array element at the time
    my @xyz = map(m/(\d*).txt/, $abc);    # single string, never saved
    print "@xyz\n";                       # only prints one value
}
```

Since `@xyz` only contains one value, it makes no difference if you print the entire array, or just the first element.

If you want this to work, you have to move the array outside the loop, and use `push`, not assignment `=` (the latter will overwrite). And remove the map statement, as it is redundant for single strings. Also, put the print statement outside the loop, or we will print some values multiple times.

```
my @abc = ('1234.txt', '2345.txt', '3456.txt', '4567.txt');
my @xyz;            # declare outside loop
foreach my $abc(@abc) {
    push @xyz, $abc =~ m/(\d*).txt/;
}
print "@xyz\n";     # print only after all values have been collected
```

But this is not the best way to do it. The for-loop is redundant if we use `map`. Both `for` and `map` loop around the values in a list/array, so doing it twice serves no purpose in this case. The solution, as has already been given by [Wes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67658876/725418) and in comments:

```
my @abc = ('1234.txt', '2345.txt', '3456.txt', '4567.txt');
my @xyz = map { m/(\d+).txt/ } @abc;
print "@xyz\n";
```

Also, you should use `\d+` when collecting numbers, as otherwise you *will* get empty string false positives for some strings. For example, the string `foo.txt` would return the empty string `""`. If you expect the whole file name to be numbers you should use a beginning-of-line anchor: `/^(\d+)\.txt/`. Also, period `.` should be escaped, because it is a regex meta character.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using `map` for each value rather than calling it once, with the entire list.  Instead, try this, which will build your `@xyz` array all at once and leave the four numbers/strings (they'll be strings but perl will convert them to integers if you try to use them as such):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @abc = ('1234.txt', '2345.txt', '3456.txt', '4567.txt');
my @xyz = map(m/(\d*).txt/, @abc);
print "@xyz\n";
```